# Remove ".git" folder from build server

Tags: git, bamboo

I am pushing latests builds from bitbucket to build server(bamboo)

pushing then to artifactory and then creating releases in Octopus.

every time I build the package for release i am getting the .git folder included.

Is there a sane way to remove the .git folder before the build server builds and releases to artifactory and Octopus?

Comment: What's your build tool?

Comment: just using bamboo as the build server. Then Powershell scripting octopus for the remainder of the nuget package. then deploy to artifact repository and octopus deploy. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the issue is that your build process is mostly (entirely?) a packaging process and runs "in place" in the source directories.

The reason this isn't a problem everybody has is, often the build process first constructs a "target" or "distribution" directory and takes whatever steps are needed to make it look *exactly* like what should be deployed, and then packages the distribution directory instead of the source directory.

This solves a lot of problems.  Probably the biggest one, when working in compiled languages, is "how do I keep from accidentally deploying source files" (and, conversely, "how do I keep from accidentally committing build artifacts into source control").

But maybe your app is mostly HTML and javascript, and you don't compile anything, and so it seems that there's no reason to have a separation between source directory and distribution directory.  I'd still encourage you to consider moving to this type of build, even if the only "build step" is to copy the needed files from the source to the distribution directory.  This is for two reasons:

First, it solves the immediate problem.  And note that the .git directory may just be the most obvious symptom.  (You may now have, or may in the future find you need, other git metadata files - like .gitignore, .gitattributes, ... - and you probably won't want those deployed either.)

Second, it sets you up for seamlessly adding more complicated source-to-distribution transformations in the future.  (Maybe you decide to minify resources for production builds.  Maybe you decide to use a web bundler.  Maybe you incorporate less stylesheets.  Maybe you start using a module-based dependency management system...)

On the flip side of the coin, deleting your git folder (no matter how "sane" a way you find to do it) might have side effects.  Depends on how your build jobs are configured, but typically the repo is kept from one build to the next to save time (by not having to fetch so much from the origin repo on each and every build).

All that said, if you want to delete the .git folder still... then what's wrong with making the first build step be a script that rm's the folder?

Comment: Selecting a build tool that is appropriate for you will do all this automatically.  Bamboo integrates with a number of good build tools, and will package all your artifacts for deploying into artifactory easily. Just pick from ant, gradle, maven, etc.

Comment: Great question and answer. Concerning the last few "projects" I have been building are typically flat files and not truly needing any compiling. So it does become a push to git, Post to bamboo, Build "Package" and Distribute to artifact and Octopus deploy.  The .git folder is just annoying in the directory being read. Nothing really more. I could rm the folder but I guess I am not sure at what point it would be "sane" to do so. My assumption was in the packaging script. And it may still be. Thank you for your insight.